# Data models not showing up in HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to make a simple API call from a .NET Core MVC application:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49897");

    var response = client.GetAsync("some-route").Result;
    var dataString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; // Unexpected data here. See below.

    [...] // deserialize dataString
}
```

`client.GetAsync(route)` successfully hits an API action method, which ultimately does this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] BindingModel bindingModel)
{
    List<SomeModel> resultObjects;

    [...] // populate resultObjects with data

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultObjects, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
}
```

But `dataString` ends up equaling this:

```
"{\"version\":{\"major\":1,\"minor\":1,\"build\":-1,\"revision\":-1,\"majorRevision\":-1,\"minorRevision\":-1},\"content\":{\"objectType\":\"System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e\",\"formatter\":{\"indent\":false,\"serializerSettings\":{\"referenceLoopHandling\":0,\"missingMemberHandling\":0,\"objectCreationHandling\":0,\"nullValueHandling\":0,\"defaultValueHandling\":0,\"converters\":[],\"preserveReferencesHandling\":0,\"typeNameHandling\":0,\"metadataPropertyHandling\":0,\"typeNameAssemblyFormat\":0,\"typeNameAssemblyFormatHandling\":0,\"constructorHandling\":0,\"contractResolver\":null,\"equalityComparer\":null,\"referenceResolver\":null,\"referenceResolverProvider\":null,\"traceWriter\":null,\"binder\":null,\"serializationBinder\":null,\"error\":null,\"context\":{},\"dateFormatString\":\"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFFK\",\"maxDepth\":null,\"formatting\":0,\"dateFormatHandling\":0,\"dateTimeZoneHandling\":3,\"dateParseHandling\":1,\"floatFormatHandling\":0,\"floatParseHandling\":0,\"stringEscapeHandling\":0,\"culture\":{}}}}}"
```

Or, in JSON format:

```
{
    version: {
        major: 1,
        minor: 1,
        [...]
    },
    content: {
        objectType: "System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"
        formatter: {
            indent: false,
            serializerSettings: {
                [...]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My list of models isn't in there at all.

What exactly is being returned, and why isn't my list of models in the response? I've looked at several online resources, and I seem to be doing things the same way as they show. This is a pretty bread-and-butter API call, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What exactly is being returned, and why isn't my list of models in the response?

What's being returned is a JSON-serialized version of your `HttpResponseMessage`, because while Web API 2 handles this type specially, **ASP.NET Core web API does not**.

To be precise, [ASP.NET Core web API supports returning the following types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types):

- `IActionResult`
- `ActionResult<T>`
- <any other type>

The first two are treated specially, but the third results in that type being JSON-serialized and returned, exactly as you saw.

In contrast, [Web API 2 supports the following special return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types):

- `void`
- `HttpResponseMessage`
- `IHttpActionResult`
- <any other type>

The correct solution is to update your code to use a custom `IActionResult` implementation instead of returning raw `HttpResponseMessage`s. [You may find this guide aids you in doing so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/webapi) - in particular, the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim) NuGet package has a [ResponseMessageResult class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.responsemessageresult) that allows you to convert your Web API controller method from this:

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Foo(Bar quux)
{
    return new BazHttpResponseMessage();
}
```

to this:

```cs
public IActionResult Foo(Bar quux)
{
    return new ResponseMessageResult(new BazHttpResponseMessage());
}
```

which should allow your current code to work as-is.