# Returning CSV from .NET Core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, asp.net-core

I'm having trouble having a .NET Core API Controller endpoint resolve to a CSV download.  I'm using the following code which I pulled from a .NET 4.5 controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id:int}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int id)
{
    string csv = await reportManager.GetReport(CustomerId, id);
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(csv);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
        new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "report.csv" };
    return response;
}
```

When I hit this endpoint from my Angular 4 app, I get the following response written to the browser:

```
{
    "version": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "build": -1,
        "revision": -1,
        "majorRevision": -1,
        "minorRevision": -1
    },
    "content": {
        "headers": [
            {
                "key": "Content-Type",
                "value": [
                    "text/csv"
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "Content-Disposition",
                "value": [
                    "attachment; filename=11.csv"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "reasonPhrase": "OK",
    "headers": [ ],
    "requestMessage": null,
    "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

My expectation is that when I hit the endpoint, the user will be prompted to download the CSV.

I found [this](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreCsvImportExport) post on how to "export" a CSV in .NET Core.  The problem is that I'm retrieving the CSV in-memory from its source (an AWS S3 bucket) whereas this code seems to only work when you have an `IEnumerable<object>`.

I'm wondering if my problem lies in either request or response headers, where there is something preventing the browser from retrieving a CSV from my API.  Here is what I see in the browser console:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting

Comment: Another notice, in such cases  often better to use outputformatters which will read acceptencoding for example, or by other rules. If you are working on a big project, you probably need to use csv export for number of methods and if you will create generic formatted you avoid unnecessary work in future. It can be a layer in middleware

Comment: @zxxc Do you have anything to add?  You linking to an article which is referenced in a link from my post isn't very helpful.

Comment: It looks as though you're fetching the download via AJAX. When you do that, you need to set the `responseType` as `arraybuffer` and create a blob out of the response data in your success method. You'll also need to handle the actual download manually, by creating a link with that data and "clicking" it. None of this happens for you automatically.

Comment: @ChrisPratt In the network traffic screenshot, I was hitting the URL directly in the browser.

Comment: @im1dermike - I've updated my answer... You want to use `FileResult` to prompt the "Save File" dialog box. This will allow you to also keep the `text/csv` content-type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data models not showing up in HttpResponseMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226019/data-models-not-showing-up-in-httpresponsemessage)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Newcomers to this question please see Svek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977036/53897). The original question is concerning http `Content-Disposition`, but it looks like search engines send generic .net core csv queries here. Svek's answer provides a good overview of the tools available to .Net Core for returning CSV data from a controller.

---

The proper way to force a file to be downloaded instead of displayed inline is using the [`Content-Disposition` response header.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) While the below solution works ([see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#applicationoctet-stream)) it's been pointed out that this can have unintended side effects.

---

#### Old Answer

Setting the `Content-Type` response header to `application/octet-stream` will force most major browsers to prompt the user to save the file instead of displaying it in the window.

Try doing something like this:

```
var result = new FileContentResult(myCsvByteArray, "application/octet-stream");
result.FileDownloadName = "my-csv-file.csv";
return result;
```

[See my answer to this similar question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307926/static-files-on-asp-net-core/46308192#46308192)

Comment: Using `application/octet-stream` is for executable files such as `exe` or `bin`... This is poor practice, as it breaks web standards and will likely impact your web application in negative ways when it comes to web crawlers and long-term maintainability, etc. There is a reason why there are web standards. You should be clear about the content you serve to your clients.

Comment: @Svek `application/octet-stream` is "This is the default value for a binary file.", for which I'd say any file counts. Your argument against using this content-type seems pretty weak but you aren't wrong that it's a bad practice. In any case I've updated my answer with the correct response header to be set which achieves the same effect.

Comment: @NeilBostian - There is little room for alternative interpretation. A `text/csv` is a **text** file, not a **binary** file... According to the web standards an **unknown text file** is `text/plain` -- and -- **unknown binary file** is `application/octet-stream`. If you just want a download prompt to show up, then return a `File` type with a `byte[]` or `stream`. Don't hack it up with `Content-Types` -- there is no need.

Comment: @Svek Treating a text file as binary is no different than treating a `string` as an `object`. Maintainability of using `application/octet-stream` vs `text/plain` is likely irrelevant in OP's case, as are web crawlers if he's specifically trying to prompt the user to download the file. This isn't going against the standard by trying to pass a text file around as video, it's just saying "Treat me as a binary blob" which isn't breaking any standard, it's making use of it.

Comment: @NeilBostian `FileResult` sets the `Content-Disposition` to `attachment` out-of-the-box as it was made to prompt the "Save" dialog box. Note that the `Content-Type` will still remain unchanged and correct as `text/csv`. There really isn't any argument that justifies using `application/octet-stream` and it shouldn't be recommended.

Answer (score 57):

## Solution: Use `FileResult`

This should be used if you want the client to get the "**Save File**" dialog box.

There are a variety to choose from here, such as `FileContentResult`, `FileStreamResult`, `VirtualFileResult`, `PhysicalFileResult`; but they all derive from `FileResult` - so we will go with that one for this example.

```
public async Task<FileResult> Download()
{
    string fileName = "foo.csv";
    byte[] fileBytes = ... ;

    return File(fileBytes, "text/csv", fileName); // this is the key!
}
```

> The above will also work if you use `public async Task<IActionResult>` if you prefer using that instead.
>
> **The key is that you return a** `File` **type.**

#### Extra: Content-Disposition

The `FileResult` will automatically provide the proper `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment`.

If you want to open the file in the browser ("inline"), instead of prompting the "Save File" dialog ("attachment"). Then you can do that by changing the `Content-Disposition` header value.

Take for example, we want to show the `PDF` file in the browser.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    byte[] contents = FetchPdfBytes();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");
    return File(contents, "application/pdf");
}
```

*Credit to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207274/3645638)*

---

## Custom Formatters

Custom formatters are a great choice in general, because they allow the client to ask for the type they want the data as, such as the more popular JSON or the less popular XML.

This primarily works by serving the content as specified in the `Accept` header that the client passes to the server, such as CSV, XLS, XML, JSON, etc.

You want to use a format type of `"text/csv"` but there is no predefined formatter for this, so you will have to manually add it to the input and output formatter collections:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new MyCustomInputFormatter());
    options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new MyCustomOutputFormatter());
});
```

#### Very Simple Custom Formatter

Here's a very simple version of a custom formatter, which is a stripped-down version that was provided with the [Microsoft Docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters).

```
public class CsvOutputFormatter : TextOutputFormatter
{
    public CsvOutputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv"));
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
    }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true; // you could be fancy here but this gets the job done.
    }

    public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        
        // your magic goes here
        string foo = "Hello World!";

        return response.WriteAsync(foo);
    }
}
```

#### Forcing a Particular Format

```
// force all actions in the controller
[Produces("text/csv")]
public class FooController
{
    // or apply on to a single action
    [Produces("text/csv")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
    }
}
```

---

For more information, I would recommend that you read:

- [Introduction to formatting response data in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting)
- [Custom formatters in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-formatters)

Comment: Is it possible to return a custom object or ActionResult<T> from the Action, but, if needed, intercept it with a custom formatter to return CSV file? I know we can return CSV as text using customer formatter. In my case, I want to return JSON data, but if the client requests a CSV, then I want to return a CSV as FILE and not CSV as text. And I was wondering if it is possible using custom formatters?

Comment: I believe your question is already answered in using Content-Disposition?

Comment: Can you add a response header in a custom formatter? I think no. 
I believe I will have to create a middleware to add the response header of Content-Disposition and a custom formatter in combination to achieve my purpose.
Please suggest if there is any alternate or better way. Thanks.