# C# Streaming to HTTP Response as CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, streaming, export-to-csv

I would like my c# MVC Controller to stream back results from my repository to a CSV.

I've seen some examples of this using a `FileResult`, however those approaches appear to rely on the entire content of the file being held in-memory as a byte array.  The CSVs I'm dealing with will potentially be large and I would like to avoid storing them in memory by streaming them straight through.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977036/4432463) shows both examples.  I began by implementing my endpoint to stream records through to the endpoint:

```
[HttpGet("download")]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Foo> StreamDownload() {
    IAsyncEnumerable<Foo> foos = fooRepository.getAll();

    await foreach(Foo foo in foos) {
        yield return convertToDto(foo);
    }
}
```

However when attempting to create a custom formatter using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-3.1), I found that HttpResponses now use [a PipeWriter to handle their I/O connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines).

I'm in the process of attempting to create a custom formatter which will read from the IAsyncEnumerable and write to the PipeWriter.  However, as this strikes me as a common enough problem, I thought it was worth checking if:

- This is the correct approach?
- Any similar converters exist already?  (I couldn't find any)
- If there's any more guides/examples worth looking at while creating this converter?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use this NuGet package to handle the CSV serialization:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Csv/

Just add the serializer to services:

```
var csvOptions = new CsvFormatterOptions {
  UseSingleLineHeaderInCsv = true,
  CsvDelimiter = ",",
  IncludeExcelDelimiterHeader = true
};

services.AddMvc().AddCsvSerializerFormatters(csvOptions);
```

..and tag the method as returning CSV:

```
[HttpGet("download")]
[Produces("text/csv")]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Foo> StreamDownload() {
    IAsyncEnumerable<Foo> foos = fooRepository.getAll();

    await foreach(Foo foo in foos) {
        yield return convertToDto(foo);
    }
}
```